# select div only if it contains select

Tags: css

Is there any CSS selector for selecting a parent div only if it directly contains a select inside ?

**Example code:**

```
<div class="top_level">
  <input type="radio"></input>
</div>
<div class="top_level">
  <input type="text"></input>
</div>
<div class="top_level">
  <select name="namehere">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Suppose I only want to select the third 3rd `top_level` class div, since it contains a select directly inside it, how would I do that ?

I did try to search around for an answer, but couldn't find any. It would have been a lot easier if parent selection was possible in CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: I guess the question might seem similar, but I'm not technically asking for a parent selector here. I'm asking if an element can be selected on the basis of what it contains. Technically they are different questions I would think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, then you can use [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) :

```
$('div.top_level:has(select)')
```

If you're using only CSS, then the answer is simple : No, you don't have anything similar to select a parent.

Comment: I want to avoid using JS here .. Looking for a purely CSS solution right now. If I can't find anything, then I'll move to JS.

Comment: @Ahmad I've edited. I'm sorry but I don't think there is a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I'll see if I can get something going without CSS. If not, I'll use this and mark your answer as the chosen one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :empty pseudo class to check whether your container is empty (excluding line breaks).

You cannot check whether it contains a type of element. But you may be able to restructure your markup to use :empty selector

eg :

```
<div class="top_level">
  <input type="radio"></input>
  <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="top_level">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <div class="list"></div>
</div>
<div class="top_level">
  <div class="list">
  <select name="namehere">
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Now you may query like

```
.list:not(:emtpy) {
                // to select all lists that are non-empty
}
```

Comment: a bit hackish though.

Comment: Small spelling error too :X Could you correct for future reference?

Comment: Can you tell me where it is ?

Comment: .list:not(:emtpy) {} this is how it is used

Comment: Indeed that is quite hacky if that's the case - using a fake selector/filter?